# Magento v1, rename country

Tags: magento-1.9, address

Is it possible to rename a country that appears in the select menu when adding an address? I'd like to rename United Kingdom to UK Mainland.

[image]

Comment: Which page are you referring to ? The frontend "add new address" page ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/Translation.php`
2. `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/fil.xml`
3. `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml`
4. `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/id.xml`
5. `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/ms.xml`